# Remove value from array based on value?

Tags: php

I have a PHP array with a parent called "items." In that array, I want to remove all values that do not contain a string (which I'm gonna use regex to find). How would I do this?

Comment: if you're just looking to match against a string, consider using strpos instead of a RegEx - faster, especially if the Array is large.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
foreach($array['items'] as $key=>$value) { // loop through the array
    if( !preg_match("/your_regex/", $value) ) {
        unset($array['items'][$key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try using [`array_filter`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php).

```
$items = array(
    #some values
);
$regex= '/^[some]+(regex)*$/i';
$items = array_filter($items, function($a) use ($regex){
    return preg_match($regex, $a) !== 0;
});
```

NOTE: This only works in PHP 5.3+.  In 5.2, you can do it this way:

```
function checkStr($a){
    $regex= '/^[some]+(regex)*$/i';
    return preg_match($regex, $a) !== 0;
}

$items = array(
    #some values
);
$items = array_filter($items, 'checkStr');
```

Comment: I prefer this approach to brute force looping over the array, good answer.